# In The Tripods, how did the Cap fix vision?

Tags: the-tripods

In *The Tripods* trilogy, Beanpole wears ordinary glasses that he was forced to invent, because as a technology they had been forgotten about. The reasoning was that the capping process would also fix your vision. But while there are brain injuries which can affect the vision which the cap might conceivably bypass or fix, that doesn’t affect basic issues with the eyes. Was the idea that the cap could somehow analyze the signal coming in from the eyes, “enhance” the image, and feed the enhanced image into the brain? Or did the Masters also correct vision problems surgically during the capping process? Or something else entirely?

Something to take into consideration is that after the signals to the caps are cut, nobody seemed to complain about being suddenly blind or anything, which hints at it being a localized process rather than a cloud-based Service, so to speak.

The answer may be different between the books and the TV series, as the way sickness was handled between them was a tad different, so please specify in your answer which one you are referring to.

Comment: I got no idea but i really like this question, upvote given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am writing this answer without direct access to the books, so it is possible that I am remembering incorrectly here.  However, I have read the books many times, and seen the first television series.  My answer applies specifically to the original books.

In any case, I think that you are making a mistake in thinking that the caps are fixing people's vision.  The reasons that only a child like Beanpole (or an uncapped adult) would wear glasses is only a child would have the  independence of mind to (1) recognize that their vision is a problem that could possibly be corrected, rather than a hardship that just needed to be endured, and (2) determine experimentally, through the necessary trial and error, how the visual correction could be done.  The caps totally stifle the wearers' capacity for independent thinking, their desire to effect change.  This is done to minimize the possibility that the enslaved peoples of Earth may rise up and destroy their masters.  People with bad vision just live with their bad vision, as folk did for millennia before the invention of optical magnification systems.

The caps ensure that the people they control are satisfied with a medieval lifestyle.  Eyeglasses were not a thing in the middle ages, so they are not available to the people of Earth during their enslavement.  The caps ensure the docility of the people, forcing them to accept the absence of many conveniences.  The fact that the population has reverted to a medieval way of life (complete with castles and knights) was a stylistic choice made by John Christopher; and it may also have been a specific choice made by the masters, to revert the inhabitants of the planet to a pre-industrial technology level so that they are not a threat.

Comment: Again, illness is treated differently between the books and the series. Upon reaching the White Mountains in the show, the boys are detained by what they think are the Guard. Among other things, the Commander holds up Beanpole’s glasses and comments that he will have no need for these soon. That’s the best example off the top of my head, weak at it is. You make a good enough argument that I need to find quotes to counter it. If I can’t, you get the prize, such as it is.

Comment: @Broklynite I'm upvoting this one as it's what I would've given as an answer. It all depends if you're asking about book continuity or TV series continuity, as there are some big differences. In my recollection the Capped simply have no reason to question their vision. If it's blurry it's blurry. It's not like they'll spend much time reading and writing anyway. There's no indication the Caps perform any function further than mind control. (Of course this may be different in the TV version).

Comment: I have found the quotes I was thinking of from the first two books. Looking at them now, I realize that I was influenced by the TV series to interpret them differently than I might have otherwise. I think the wording is somewhat ambiguous (“not being allowed to wear the lenses, you must blunder through a world in which you will see less clearly than your fellows”), but without anything better than ambiguous to the contrary, I cannot see a reason not to accept this answer.